# Populating a Data Grid View in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp

I'm developing a win forms application in MVP pattern. In the application, there is a small module to show the branch offices (called points) where the attendance entering process has been completed. Those details should be shown in a data grid view.

So I have a form (View), a presenter and a data service classes. For the simplicity I'm not using a "model class" for this as the only intended functionality is populating the grid view.

Form `frmAttendancePoints` and `DataService` class have implemented  `IAttendancePointsView` and `IDataService` interfaces respectively.

My question: Is the way I'm populating the grid correct? If not could you please let me know a better solution.

**View**

```
public partial class frmAttendancePoints : Form, IAttendancePointsView
{
        private void frmEnterAttendance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowAttendancePoints(sender, e);
        }

        public void LoadAttendacePointsGridWithData(DataTable dt)
        {
            dgAttendancePoints.DataSource = dt;
        }

        public event EventHandler ShowAttendancePoints;
}
```

**Presenter**

```
class AttendancePointPresenter : BasePresenter
{
    IAttendancePointsView _View;
    IDataService _ds;

    public AttendancePointPresenter(IAttendancePointsView View, IDataService ds)
    {
        _View = View;
        _ds = ds;
        WireUpViewEvents();
    }

    private void WireUpViewEvents()
    {
        this._View.ShowAttendancePoints +=new EventHandler(_View_ShowAttendancePoints);
    }

    private void _View_ShowAttendancePoints(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowAttendancePoints();
    }

    private void ShowAttendancePoints()
    {
        var dt = _ds.GetAttendancePoints();
        this._View.LoadAttendacePointsGridWithData(dt);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        _View.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**DataService**

```
public class DataServie
{
        public DataTable GetAttendancePoints()
        {
            string selectStatement = "SELECT PID, point_name + ', ' + point_add AS point, area, sm, atten_status FROM Point WHERE Status='Active'";
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
                    {
                        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                ds.Tables.Add(dt);    
                                sqlConnection.Open();
                                da.Fill(dt);
                                return dt;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Programme**

```
    IAttendancePointsView AttendancePointView = new frmAttendancePoints();
    IDataService ds = new DataService();

    var Presenter = new AttendancePointPresenter(AttendancePointView, ds);
    Presenter.Show();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *For the simplicity I'm not using a "model class" for this [...]*

Then it's not *Model*-View-Presenter you have here.

> ```
> var Presenter = new AttendancePointPresenter(AttendancePointView, ds);
> ```

I love it. What you've done here, is called *Dependency Injection* - more specifically, *constructor injection*. It's a technique that, when applied consistently, greatly contributes to making your code more *cohesive* and less *coupled*.

I think `AttendancePointView` being a local variable, should be named `attendancePointView`, or simply `view` - same for `Presenter`, it's a local variable, should be `presenter`; and `ds` could simply be called `service`, so the presenter code would read:

```
var presenter = new AttendancePointPresenter(view, service);
presenter.Show();
```

Which is awesome! Well done!

The only thing is that in `Program.cs` it doesn't matter that the view and the service are injected as interfaces, since `Program` is *coupled* with `frmAttendancePoints` and `DataService` anyway. I'd write it like this:

```
var view = new frmAttendancePoints();
var service = new DataService();

var presenter = new AttendancePointPresenter(view, service);
presenter.Show();
```

The presenter still receives its dependencies as abstractions, per its constructor.

---

> **View**

You're declaring an event that *looks* more like a method:

> ```
> public event EventHandler ShowAttendancePoints;
> ```

Seeing that it's raised when the form gets loaded...

> ```
> private void frmEnterAttendance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     ShowAttendancePoints(sender, e);
> }
> ```

That event does nothing that `Load` doesn't do. I think you should have an `IView` interface that exposes that `Load` event, and everything a presenter needs to know about any view:

```
public interface IView
{
    event EventHandler Load;
    void ShowDialog();
    void BindModel(IModel model);
}
```

Now the form's code can look like this<sup>*</sup>:

```
public partial class frmAttendancePoints : Form, IView
{
    public frmAttendancePoints()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    public void BindModel(IModel model)
    {
        dgAttendancePoints.DataSource = model;
    }
}
```

---

> **DataService**

This class should spit out your *model*, not a boilerplate-level `DataTable`.

One thing though, is that you can stack the `using` blocks for fewer levels of indentation:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);    
    sqlConnection.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

---

<sub>*This might need a bit of work, I'm not sure a WinForms `DataGridView.DataSource` can be assigned just like that, but you get the idea ;)</sub>

Comment: Thanks 4 ur quick rpl! "That event does nothing that Load doesn't do..." >> I'm under the impression that instead of having another event, I can utilize form's existing load event to start the process. So that I have to put a listener in the presenter to this load event and then the presenter can call BindModel() method in the form correct?                                      "This class should spit out your model, not a boilerplate-level DataTable." >> Yeah I have to find a way of doing this as it is supposed to return not a single model rather set of models (All branch offices)